# Get paragraphs of data out from a word doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have this google doc and I want to extract the text into an excel where each row has each product's service description. Some of the paragraphs are as below-

Adaptive Image Compression: Adaptive Image Compression detects the current network conditions between a client and an Akamai edge server. It may dynamically re-compress image files, reducing file size and assisting in faster transmission of the image file.

Adaptive Media Delivery: Adaptive Media Delivery is optimized for adaptive bit rate streaming. This provides a high-quality viewing experience across varying network types and speeds, including mobile. Adaptive Media Delivery delivers both live and on-demand streaming media; and, since it's built on Akamai, it provides scalability, reliability, availability, and reach.

Adaptive Media Player for Devices – Android SDK: Adaptive Media Player for Devices (Android SDK) is a software SDK. It enables audio and video playback in popular Android-based mobile and TV platform formats. The software is delivered in executable format without source code, and configuration is performed by developers with available configuration objects, parameters, and client-side APIs. Using the player does not require Akamai delivery Services.

Adaptive Media Player for Devices – Premier: Adaptive Media Player for Devices (Premiere) is a software SDK. It enables audio and video playback in popular mobile and TV platform formats. Premier includes business-critical third-party capabilities for monetization and measurement. The software is delivered in executable format without source code, and configuration is performed by developers with available configuration objects, parameters, and client-side APIs. Using the player does not require Akamai delivery Services.

There are more than 200 such paragraphs, how can I easily extract each in to a row in an excel or google sheet.

Please help

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly imagine your situation from your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Google Document including 200 paragraphs.
- You want to retrieve all paragraphs from the Document and put them into a Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Apps Script. And, please set `documentId`, `spreadsheetId`, and `sheetName`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const documentId = "###"; // Please set your Google Document ID.
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Google Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  // Retrieve paragraphs from the Document.
  const paragraphs = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody().getParagraphs();
  const values = paragraphs.map(p => [p.getText().trim()]).filter(String);

  // Put the paragraphs into a Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run with valid values of `documentId`, `spreadsheetId`, and `sheetName`, the texts of all paragraphs are retrieved from the Document. And, the retrieved texts are put into a Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [getParagraphs() of Class Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getparagraphs)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [setValues(values) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: @Kimberly_Jennifer Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. Also, I added a tag of `google-apps-script`.